# How to compute exterior derivative of generalized angular form in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, differential-operators

On $\mathbb R^n$, with $m\in\mathbb Z$, I want to calculate the exterior derivative of the angular form
\begin{align}
w=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\frac{x_i}{\|x\|^m}dx_1\cdots dx_{i-1}\hspace{0.03cm}\widehat{dx_{i}}\hspace{0.03cm}dx_{i+1}\cdots dx_n
\end{align}
This is the exercise 6 page 261 from the book Analysis on Manifolds of Munkres. First of all, I have no clue what is the meaning of the symbol $\widehat{dx_i}$.Though, I have tried out and got
\begin{align}
dw&=d\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\frac{x_i}{\| x \|^m}dx_1\cdots dx_{i-1}\hspace{0.03cm}\widehat{dx_{i}}\hspace{0.03cm}dx_{i+1}\cdots dx_n \right)
\newline &=\sum_{i=1}^nd\left[(-1)^{i-1}\frac{x_i}{\|x\|^m}\right]dx_1\cdots dx_{i-1}\hspace{0.03cm}\widehat{dx_{i}}\hspace{0.03cm}dx_{i+1}\cdots dx_n\tag1
\end{align}
For each $i=1,\dots n$, we have
\begin{align}
d\left[(-1)^{i-1}\frac{x_i}{\|x\|^m}\right]&=(-1)^{i-1}\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_j\left(\frac{x_i}{\|x\|^m}\right)dx_j
\newline &=(-1)^{i-1}\sum_{\substack{j=1\\ j\ne i}}^n\frac{-mx_ix_j}{\|x\|^{m+2}}dx_j+(-1)^{i-1}\frac{1-mx_i^2\|x\|^{-2}}{\|x\|^m}dx_i\tag2
\end{align}
But here I don't know how complicated the equation (1) would be if I substituted (2) into (1). Is there any simple way for me to do this ? Thanks

Comment: I'm quite confident that Munkres defined that hat symbol the first time it appeared: It means that you should omit that term in the long wedge product. And you certainly need to know and remember the properties of wedge product: For any $j\ne i$, the $dx_j$ term in your expression will disappear when you wedge with all the $dx_k$ except $dx_i$.

Comment: ok, so let try with the case $n=2$. We have $$w=\displaystyle\frac{x_1}{\|x\|^m}\widehat{dx_1}dx_2-\frac{x_2}{\|x\|^m}dx_1\widehat{dx_2}$$Then, 
\begin{align}dw=&-\displaystyle\frac{mx_1x_2}{\|x\|^{m+2}}dx_2\widehat{dx_1}dx_2-\frac{mx_2x_1}{\|x\|^{m+2}}dx_1dx_1\widehat{dx_2} \newline &+\frac{1-mx_1^2\|x\|^{-2}}{\|x\|^m}dx_1\widehat{dx_1}dx_2+\frac{1-mx_2^2\|x\|^{-2}}{\|x\|^m}dx_2dx_1\widehat{dx_2} \newline =&\hspace{.05cm}\frac{1-mx_1^2\|x\|^{-2}}{\|x\|^m}dx_1\widehat{dx_1}dx_2+\frac{1-mx_2^2\|x\|^{-2}}{\|x\|^m}dx_2dx_1\widehat{dx_2}\end{align} Is this what you meant ?

Comment: I’m not checking the details. Just omit the terms. Write the form as blah $dx_2$ plus blah $dx_1$.